# Fetch data from core data without section

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am new in iOS and core data. Can anyone give me a example to fetch data from core data through NSFetchedResultsController and display in UITableView

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [New to Core Data for iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656476/new-to-core-data-for-iphone)

Comment: try https://coderwall.com/p/e26c7w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is almost too general for this platform. You are expected to at least try something yourself.

One obvious thing to do is to look at the documentation. You should have found out that the core data template in Xcode has a functioning table view based on NSFetchedResultsController.

- Create new project
- Choose master-detail
- Check Core Data
- Examine the master view controller